# Anything that can maintain the order of two or more QuerySets when they are merged

Tags: python, django, python-itertools

I have two different models whose QuerySets I want to combine together. I have seen that I can use itertools.chain to concatenate them together whilst retaining their iterator-ness

Assuming both sets are ordered the same, I want an iterator that you can give both QuerySets and the field(s) by which they are ordered and then it will interleave the two or more sets, retaining the order that they both share. The QuerySets could both be very large so I don't want to process them as lists. Anyone know of anything?

Back in the pre DBMS day when I was a mainframe Cobol programmer, this kind of thing was my bread and butter.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a generator I have written that does the interleaving. I haven't tested it exhaustively but it does seem to work.

```
def interleave(query1, query2, field=None, order='ASC'):

    iter1 = query1.iterator()
    iter2 = query2.iterator()

    next_1 = next(iter1, None)
    next_2 = next(iter2, None)

    while next_1 and next_2:
        if order == 'ASC':
            if getattr(next_1, field ) < getattr(next_2, field):
                yield next_1
                next_1 = next(iter1, None)
            else:
                yield next_2
                next_2 = next(iter2, None)
        else:
            if getattr(next_1, field ) >= getattr(next_2, field):
                yield next_1
                next_1 = next(iter1, None)
            else:
                yield next_2
                next_2 = next(iter2, None)

    if next_1:
        yield next_1
        while iter1:
            yield next(iter1)

    if next_2:
        yield next_2
        while iter2:
            yield next(iter2)
```